# Why do function template arguments come through as extra function arguments when passed into a macro?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having this issue with a larger code, but have re-created the issue with a simple example.

I have a templated function (numberFunc) which takes two template arguments. I want to pass this function into a macro (macroFunction) and use the macro to do something else with it. The below code works fine for 1 template argument, but as soon as I have 2 as shown I get:

> error: macro "macroFunction" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
> macroFunction(numberFunc<AccessorType, Node>, 0);

As far as I can tell it should still only be passing 2 arguments into macroFunction. Am I missing something here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// macro we want to call
#define macroFunction(a__, b__) printf("%d\n", a__());

// to be used as template arguments
struct Node {
    int idx;
    void Run();
};

struct AccessorType {
    int idx;
};

// function with two template arguments
template <class Accessor, class N> int numberFunc() {
    return 17;
}

// example normal function which works
void otherFunction(int a(), int b) {
    printf("%d\n", a());
}

int main() {
    
    // this works
    otherFunction(numberFunc<AccessorType, Node>, 0);
    
    // but this throws an error (too many arguments)
    macroFunction(numberFunc<AccessorType, Node>, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tl;dr: The preprocessor doesn't understand templates. It only sees the commas here.

Comment: If you are using the g++ compiler, you could pass the option -E to see the preprocessed output. This should tell you why you are seeing the error when compiling.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`a__`, `b__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.